# Slim + PHP + MySQLi : Exception: Identifier "select * from users" is not defined

Tags: php, mysqli, slim

This is my db_david.php file:

```
<?php

    $app->get('/db', function() {
        require_once 'connection.php';

        $query = "select * from users";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        while($row = $this->$query->fetch_aasoc()){
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    });
?>
```

This is content of connection.php :

```
  <?php
        $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $pass = ".....";
        $db_name = "....";

        $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);
    ?>
```

This is content of index.php:

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../libs/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true]]);

require_once '../include/db_david.php'; 
$app->run();


?>
```

I am getting Slim Application Error. The Application could not run because of following error:

```
Type: Slim\Exception\ContainerValueNotFoundException
Message: Identifier "select * from users" is not defined.
File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/task_manager/libs/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Container.php
Line: 120
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fetching the data in entirely the wrong way...

```
$query = "select * from users";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){   // Fetch the value from the result
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Also note the mistype of `fetch_aasoc()`

Comment: New exception: Message: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_aasoc()
File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/task_manager/include/db_david.php

Comment: As I mentioned `fetch_aasoc` is a mistake - should be `fetch_assoc` (2 ss, not 2 aa)

Answer (score 1):

First sight, There is a typo in query property

```
$this->$query->fetch_assoc()){
```

Should be

```
$this->query->fetch_assoc()){
```

Comment: New exception: Type: Slim\Exception\ContainerValueNotFoundException
Message: Identifier "query" is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approach, make use of Slim's dependency container.

The idea is you register a function to the container that will return an instance of the connection object to your application.

A quick example follows

```
<?php

use Slim\App;
use Slim\Container;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

require_once("../vendor/autoload.php");

// create your slim application with a dependency container
$app = new App( new Container );

// get the container
$container = $app->getContainer();

// add a function that returns instance of dependency
$container['database'] = function($container) {

    return new \mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'yourdbname');

};

$app->get('/', function(Request $req, Response $res, $args){

    $query = $this->database->query("select * from table");
    // do something with the result

});
```

A huge benefit of this approach is that you don't need to require any more files inside your routes. Imagine if you move that connection.php file, thats a lot of code you need to update, with this approach you only have to mess with the factory.

Highly suggest you read the following https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/concepts/di.html